# Get value input text jstl - Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

My friends,

I have problem.

I'm working with spring MVC and I put value in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="projetoid" id="projId"/>
```

I'd like to get valeu of "projetoid" and pass as argument:

```
<p><s:message code="modal.projeto.confirma_desativacao" arguments="???"  htmlEscape="false"/></p>
```

Any idea? How can I get this value with JSTL?

Comment: What is the taglib uri for the prefix s? Is it jstl fmt?

Comment: <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

Comment: For the 's' prefix, is it really "springframework.org/tags" and not "springframework.org/tags/form"?

Answer (score 0):

There's a little difficulty understanding your question, but I perceived it as you want the value in projId to be passed into the s:message arguments attribute. Here is what I have tested and found working.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="hidden" name="projetoid" id="projId" value="testing123"/>

    <p><s:message id="target" code="modal.projeto.confirma_desativacao" arguments="???"  htmlEscape="false"/></p>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var hiddenVal = $('#projId').val();
            $('#target').attr("arguments", hiddenVal);
            console.log('Logged: '+$('#target').attr("arguments"));
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I could see the console.log successfully printed the value of projId.

I used jQuery to do the job. When the document is ready, I passed the value from projId to id:target. If you are trying to pass the value upon form submit, then you have to create a function to transfer the value over upon submitting the form. Hope this helps =)